# Huppert, III.19.2: How to construct a homomorphism from a $p$-group into the center of a maximal subgroup?

Tags: group-homomorphism, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $N$ a maximal subgroup (so $G/N$ has order $p$) such that $Z(N) \leq Z(G)$. III.19.2 in Huppert's Book "Endliche Gruppen I" says that there exists a non-inner automorphism of $G$ of order $p$.

In the proof of Hilfssatz III.19.2, Huppert starts with a homomorphism $\tau: G\to Z(N)$ which is non-trivial and has $\ker\tau = N$. He makes no statement on why such a homomorphism exist.

How does one prove that such a homomorphism exists? Can one even explicitly describe such a homomorphism? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $G/N$ is cyclic of order $p$. $Z(N)$ is a nontrivial abelian $p$ group. There's going to be homomorphisms! Just pick a nontrivial element of order $p$ in $Z(N)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to try to make such a morphism (somewhat) explicit,  we have little choice but to start with the canonical projection $\pi:G\to G/N\cong \Bbb Z_p.$

Then since $N$ is a $p$-group,  it has non-trivial center $Z(N).$  So it's got an element of order $p$, hence $\Bbb Z_p$ embedds in $\Bbb Z(N).$   Let $i:\Bbb Z_p\to Z(N)$ be an embedding.

Finally,  just compose:  $$\tau :=i\circ \pi.$$

Comment: Many thanks, haven't thought about the ingenious route through $G/N$ :-)